# Elasticsearch how to filter document from a specific date (epoch format)

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is what I get when I look at the mapping

```
   "timestamp" : {
      "type" : "date"
    },
```

Here is what I get when I do a basic _search

```
GET my_index/_search

{
  "timestamp" : 1.645890645150344E12,
}
```

As you can see it is written as an EPOCH format

Here is my request to get all of the document with a timestamp superior of 02/06/2022 (translate as **1.6575224644905708E12** in EPOCH time)

EDIT:

```
 GET my_index/_search {   "query": {
     "bool": {
       "filter": [
         { "range": {"timestamp": { "gte": "1654128000"}}}
       ]
     }}}
```

However all the document I get have an timestamp **1.6575224644905708E12** which is equal to **Thursday, January 1, 1970** (seem my filter condition doesn't work)

I have try different approach like comparing the timestamp with a date with the following format "2022-06-02"

Any idea about how I can compare EPOCH time to get every document from a specific date ?

EDIT:

I'm using version 7.16.2

Thank you

Comment: I have never seen such a format ... which version of Elasticsearch are you running ?
`1.645890645150344E12` => `1645890645150` => `Saturday, 26 February 2022 15:50:45.150` so it sounds about right, it is `epoch_ms`. But I have never seen it displayed this way

Comment: You're actually right, however can you tell me why 1.645890645150344E12 become 1645890645150 ? (I understand why 1645890645150 is Saturday, 26 February 2022)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.645890645150344E12

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

You might be victim of dynamic mapping.
But I am not sure why your search is not working, as range work with number too.

## To reproduce

```json
PUT 73910820/
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict", 
    "properties": {
      "@timestamps":{
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_millis"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST 73910820/_doc/1
{
  "@timestamp": 1.645890645150344E12
}

GET 73910820/_mapping
```

You should see `@timestamp` with 2 mappings

```json
{
  "73910820": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "@timestamps": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

whereas if you were to make the mapping strict you would not be able to index the documents.

```json
PUT 73910820/
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict", 
    "properties": {
      "@timestamps":{
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_millis"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST 73910820/_doc/1
{
  "@timestamp": 1.645890645150344E12
}
```